# Is it possible for a fluid table to have the same spacing between AND outside each of the items?

Tags: html, css

I was given a problem crafted by someone with little to no CSS knowledge: "Make each column in a table be padded equally from the left of the table, the right of the table, and adjacent items."

The table itself is supposed to be fluid; the width of each of the items that are contained within it are uncertain. Worse yet, although right now the tables in question have two columns, they are for visual effects and will probably be updated to 3-4 columns.

I know CSS doesn't support the adding of pixels and percents, but is there anything remotely close to fixing this problem?

The best draw-up I can do for this (on GIMP, anyway):
[image]

An example set of tables that don't quite work:
http://jsfiddle.net/22vmb4gp/2/

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;    
}
td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #FFDDDD;
}
div {
    border: 2px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr:first-child:before,
tr:last-child:after {
    display:table-cell;
    content:'';
    width: 10%;
    border:1px solid #DDFFDD;
}
```

Comment: You could, although not very elegant, create some empty spacer tds. http://jsfiddle.net/a4mswzm1/1/

Comment: Unless these tables are holding actual data, versus for looks, you should advocate to use better semantics

Comment: @RyanB What can I say except: SharePoint 2010, Internet Explorer 8 compatibility mode. The proposed solution was so good that it eradicates the need for a table, but... SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of tables, and these days it's bad practice to use them. However, there is a way to do what you're asking using only CSS.

Here's your HTML without tables:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">Item 1</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 2</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 3</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 4</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 5</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">Item 1</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 2</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 3</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 4</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">Item 1</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 2</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">Item 1</div>
    <div class="inner">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS that will create what you're looking for:

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: 1px solid #FFDDDD;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.inner {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

You can read more about Flex [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).